# Error when trying to use the DB assembler: Can't find any matching row in the user table

Tags: azerothcore

In my AzerothCore app, I'm trying to run the following command:

```
bin/acore-db-asm 5
```

But I'm getting the following error:

> ERROR 1133 (42000) at line 1: Can't find any matching row in the user table

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to edit my `config.sh` file and replace all occurrences of:

```
MYSQL_HOST='127.0.0.1';
```

with:

```
MYSQL_HOST='localhost';
```